# Generate data into recharts bar chart using List of DTO

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, recharts

I have this DTO object generated from Rest API using Typescript:

```
export interface BillingSummaryDTO {
    paid?: number,
    outstanding?: number,
    pastDue?: number,
    cancelled?: number,
    createdAt?: Moment | null,
}

export async function getBillingSummary(): Promise<AxiosResponse<BillingSummaryDTO[]>> {
  return await axios.get<BillingSummaryDTO[]>(
      `${baseUrl}/management/billing/summary`
  );
}
```

Example chart:

```
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "recharts";
import {Box} from "@material-ui/core";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Jan",
    Chargebacks: 4000,
    Transactions: 2400,
    USD: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: "Feb",
    Chargebacks: 3000,
    Transactions: 1398,
    USD: 2210,
  },
  {
    name: "Mar",
    Chargebacks: 2000,
    Transactions: 9800,
    USD: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: "Apr",
    Chargebacks: 2780,
    Transactions: 3908,
    USD: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: "May",
    Chargebacks: 1890,
    Transactions: 4800,
    USD: 2181,
  },
  {
    name: "Jun",
    Chargebacks: 2390,
    Transactions: 3800,
    USD: 2500,
  },
  {
    name: "Jul",
    Chargebacks: 3490,
    Transactions: 4300,
    USD: 2100,
  },
  {
    name: "Aug",
    Chargebacks: 3490,
    Transactions: 4300,
    USD: 2100,
  },
  {
    name: "Sep",
    Chargebacks: 3490,
    Transactions: 4300,
    USD: 2100,
  },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: "center",
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
  })
);

const usePaperStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        width: theme.spacing(16),
        height: theme.spacing(16),
      },
    },
  })
);

const useTimelineStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    padding: "6px 16px",
  },
  secondaryTail: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

export default function Billing() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const classesPaper = usePaperStyles();
  const classesTimeline = useTimelineStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={11}>
          {/*Padding on the top*/}
          <Box m="5rem" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} >
          <h4 className="chart-label">Invoices Summary</h4>
          <BarChart
            width={1000}
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
              top: 5,
              right: 30,
              left: 20,
              bottom: 5,
            }}
            barSize={30}
          >
            <XAxis
              dataKey="name"
              scale="point"
              padding={{ left: 10, right: 10 }}
            />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <Bar
              dataKey="Transactions"
              fill="#8884d8"
              background={{ fill: "#eee" }}
            />
          </BarChart>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

How I can use data from `BillingSummaryDTO[]` to generate the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a function that maps over BillingSummaryDTO[] and converts it into the data model (as visible in the variable `data`)  that you have specified for consumption by the `<BarChart/>` is a valid approach.

```
export interface BarChartDataModel {
  name: string,
  Chargebacks: number,
  Transactions: number,
  USD: number,
}

const data : BarChartDataModel []
```

This data will be used in `<BarChart/>` as

```
<BarChart
            data={data}
            // ....
          >
         // ...
 </BarChart>
```

Such a function will follow the `map` `reduce` approach with a little help from a JS date management library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)

4 step solution

1. Arrange all bills chronologically (oldest bill first) for easier map-reduce later
2. Bucket bills by year into buckets called 'yearwise-buckets'
3. Bucket bills in each yearwise-bucket into buckets called 'monthwise-bucket'
4. Reduce all bills in each monthwise-bucket to an object following the `BarChartDataModel` interface. A collection of objects following the `BarChartDataModel` interface is the `data` we pass to our `<BarChart/>` component
5. Consume this object collection inn our `<BarChart/>` component

Your code for the same would be :

```
export interface BillingSummaryDTO {
    paid?: number,
    outstanding?: number,
    pastDue?: number,
    cancelled?: number,
    createdAt?: Moment | null,
}

export interface BarChartDataModel {
  name: string,
  Chargebacks: number,
  Transactions: number,
  USD: number,
}

export async function getBillingSummary(): Promise<AxiosResponse<BillingSummaryDTO[]>> {
  const response = await axios.get<BillingSummaryDTO[]>(
      `${baseUrl}/management/billing/summary`
  );
  // STEP 1 : Chronological ordering. Oldest bills will show first
  const chronologicallyOrdered = response.sort((a:BillingSummaryDTO,b:BillingSummaryDTO)=> a.createdAt - b.createdAt )

  // STEP 2 : Bucket by year
  const groupByYear = chronologicallyOrdered.reduce((yearwiseBills : any, bill:BillingSummaryDTO, currIdx:number)) => 
     {
        const year = moment(bill.createdAt).year().toString()
        if(!yearwiseBills[year]){ 
          yearwiseBills[year] = []
        } 
        yearwiseBills[year].push(bill)
        return yearwiseBills
     }
  ,{})

  // STEP 3 : In each yearwise bucket -> bucket by month
  const groupByMonth = Object.keys(groupByYear).map((year, yearwiseBills) => yearwiseBills.reduce((monthwiseBills: any, bill:BillingSummaryDTO, currIdx:number)) => 
     {
        const moment = moment(bill.createdAt).month().toString()
        if(!yearAcc[month]){ 
          monthwiseBills[month] = []
        } 
        monthwiseBills[month].push(bill)
        return monthwiseBills
     }
  ,{}) );

 // STEP 4 : Reduce all bills in a monthwise bucket into a monthlyReport object and store all monthlyReport objects in an monthlyReportArray
 const monthlyReportArray:BarChartDataModel[] = Object.keys(groupByMonth).map((year, yearwiseBills) => 
   Object.keys(bills).map((month, monthwiseBills) => monthwiseBills.reduce((monthlyReport:BarChartDataModel,bill:BillingSummaryDTO) => {
    if(bill.cancelled){
      monthlyReport.Chargebacks++
    }else{
      monthlyReport.Transactions++,
      monthlyReport.USD += bill.paid
    }
    return monthlyReport
  },{
    name : moment(month, 'M').format('MMM')
    Transactions : 0,
    USD : 0,
    Chargebacks:0
   } )
 )


 // STEP 5 : Consume this as the "data" for the "<BarChart/>" component
 return monthlyReportArray
}
```

I bucketed by year first and then bucketed by month instead of directly bucketing by month because we don't want to combine the monthly reports of say "May of 1997" and "May of 1998" into just "May" for our chart. We would want them to be separate

Comment: I get multiple errors. Are you sure that this should be proper solution?

Comment: Can you please share your errors ? The method for map-reduce is perfect, so the logic sticks. Syntax issues might occur (mainly type-checking errors).